# iOS Core Data error when updating

Tags: core-data

I want to update a field in a table. However when I save after fetching and modifying the field, error 1570 is thrown. [Mandatory value is nil].

```
MyAppDelegate *appdelegate = DELEGATE;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyTable" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(myAttribute_id = %@)",myAttribute.attribute_id];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
for (myAttribute *obj in results) {
    NSLog(@"myAttribute_id : %@",myAttribute.attribute_id);

    [obj setValue:myAttribute.attribute2_id forKey:@"attribute2_id"];
    [context save:&error];
    NSLog(@"save error : %@",error);
}
```

Here I get an error. Whereas all mandatory fields are already set.

Comment: What is the full text from the error?